# Menu with Active trails activated when viewing views

Tags: drupal, menu, view, taxonomy

I'm using Drupal 7. I have a menu with links to specific views. They have links in menu with active trails - there is no problem with them. The views are based on a contextual filter connected with some terms from a `Taxonomy` dictionary. Every view has a different term.

For example:

```
View 1 (term 1)
View 2 (term 2)
View 3 (term 3)
```

`View 1 (as page):` has some links to content with term 1, `View 2 (as page):` has some links to content with term 2 etc.

The problem starts when I enter some link from `Views` which is assigned to that term. In the menu, `active menu trail` in the links is disabled.

How I can made it work? Could anybody send me solution for setting up a view in such a way that it will "talk" to the menu and set the `active trail` argument to link when it will be from that view?

I checked `Taxonomy_menu` and `Taxonomy_menu_trails` but it's not a solution.

Comment: Maybe I need to use context https://drupal.org/project/menu_block with http://drupal.org/project/context_menu_block ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I know what is solution for that problem.

I need to use Context module. (CONTEXT UI)

As a requiments I need to add:

1. my view linked from View 1
2. term from dictionary

As a reaction:

1. Menu (linked to View 1)

It`s a really simple.